# Match exact value with FullText search in MyISAM

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, myisam

I have  a table with 2 columns as Email and ID. I want to search exact matching Email value in column.

I have setup my Table with MyISAM Engine and set Email column with FullText index. When I run query to search for exact match it sometimes work and sometimes it fails.

this is my table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_email` (
    `email` varchar(60),
    `uid` int(11)
    FULLTEXT KEY `EmailIndex` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And this is my Query to match against my email value

```
select uid from tbl_email where MATCH(email) AGAINST ('abcdefghi@yahoo.com') 
limit 1;
```

It sometimes work and sometimes it fails to return matching result even though there is a matching result in table. Am I doing anything wrong? What should I do to match exact value in FullText searching?

I also tried using **IN BOOLEAN MODE** but that is same no use like this

```
select uid from tbl_email where MATCH(email) AGAINST ('abcdefghi@yahoo.com' 
IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 1;
```

Comment: why use full text at all ?you should just use: `select uid from tbl_email where email='abcdefghi@yahoo.com' limit 1;`

Comment: it intermittently fails on the SAME string when you run the same identical query multiple times? Or on different strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know that FullText index searching interprets the search string as a phrase in natural human language and breaks words if necessary for searching as said on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html and most important look here

**The stopword list applies. In addition, words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match. **

And I believe that your every email will have **.com** (. as stopword) in it meaning your whole table will be matched against your provided search.

You better go with simple indexing with InnoDB as it will be better for faster inserting of records and make simple where clause.

I don't know what algorithm is used for FullText searching as opposed to normal index for string search but suppose if you are doing it with FullText indexing, I guess due to different interpretations it will take more than normal index because then it will have to look every email value as all have stop words like @ and .com etc. But this is just my understanding I am not a Data Search Algorithm Maker.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to match using full text, you can simply run:

```
SELECT uid FROM tbl_email WHERE email='abcedfghi@yahoo.com' LIMIT 1;
```

That query should return exactly what you want to fetch.

Comment: So Don't I have to use FullText index for my table?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL 5.5 reference page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) when using `FULLTEXT` to find exact phrases you would enclose them in single and double quotes.  The single quotes are delimiters while the double quotes encapsulate your query.

e.g. : `... MATCH(email) AGAINST('"someone@example.com"') ...`

However, echoing what others have already said, a simple `WHERE` clause outta get you by from the looks of your query.  I think `FULLTEXT` is better suited to find keywords in heaps of information within a record, not single value fields like an email field.

Comment: So Don't I have to use FullText index for my table? Would not FullText make my query faster to search?

Comment: @CodeDevil If you want to make that field faster when searching, simply create a regular index on it.   Use `FULLTEXT` indexes for searching keywords in bigger sets of information.

Comment: I think you are right. Because I tried my best to make this.

Comment: Will then InnoDB be enough for simple indexing of text content?

Comment: IMO, InnoDB is better and MyISAM for a few different reasons, like native support for constraints.  However in MySQL 5.5 and below you can't use `FULLTEXT`, you can in 5.6+ though. If you don't require MyISAM for some special reason I would certainly recommend InnoDB.  Then index your `email` field and run simple `WHERE` clauses against it, that would probably be pretty quick enough for getting an email address.  If you find yourself using `LIKE` clauses with the `%` wildcards - avoid using it on the left hand side of your string at all costs!  Left hand side will nullify your index purpose.